# How to fix 'write callback called multiple times'

Tags: gulp, node-modules

I am suddenly getting a gulp error that I don't understand for a project that was previously running fine. I haven't changed anything in my gulpfile.js, so I don't understand what caused the error. Can anyone enlighten me?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: write callback called multiple times
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:84:31)
    at EventEmitter.signals.on.err (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/gulp-cache/lib/index.js:451:7)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.onError (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/gulp-cache/lib/index.js:288:15)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/through2-concurrent/through2-concurrent.js:37:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:558:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:84:17)
    at EventEmitter.signals.on.err (/Users/hannah/Documents/random projects/salamander/node_modules/gulp-cache/lib/index.js:451:7)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this issue:

I found out that the error was coming from my image minifying task (gulp-imagemin). I had some SVG files in my image folder that I think were structured incorrectly or something. I removed them from the image folder and then gulp started running again.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually due to we are using the imagemin's plugins along with cache.

Please run this **npm rebuild jpegtran-bin** this will reset it, and run your gulp task comment again!.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was optimization with **imagemin.gifsicle()** and a big animated gif-file (57Mb). Resaving the image with PhotoShop didn't help. I'm not sure about the root of the problem, but removing the file solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a dumb one... I am using through2 to pipe and replace the contents of my file and wrapped it as a function.  Well, this function was trying to console.log a variable that never gets defined in the branch of logic it was called from.

So yeah, the error message made me look deeper than I needed to since I would have expected an undefined type error instead of the 'write callback called multiple times' I got.