# Gulp JS task outputting NodeError: Callback called multiple times

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-file-include

### Gulp JS task outputting NodeError: Callback called multiple times

I have five Gulp JS tasks, one of these tasks called `js_bundle` is giving me an error. The error is as follows:

> ***NodeError:** Callback function called multiple times*

*Here is my `gulpfile.js`:*

```js
const { src, dest, parallel , series , watch } = require('gulp');

const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const minify = require('gulp-minifier');
const strip = require('gulp-strip-comments');
const rtlcss = require('gulp-rtlcss');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

// sass.compiler = require('node-sass'); // no-need for gulp-sass v5+

var node_path = '../../../';


function html(cb) {
  src('html/src/**')
  .pipe(dest('html/dist/'));

  cb();
}

function scss(cb) {
  src(['scss/*.scss'])
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())               // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))  // uses {outputStyle: 'compressed'} in saas() for minify css
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))          // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/css'));

  src(['scss/*.scss', '!scss/style-email.scss'])
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())               // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))  // uses {outputStyle: 'compressed'} in saas() for minify css
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))          // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(rtlcss())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.rtl' }))
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/css'));

  // EDITORS
  src(['scss/editors/*.scss'])
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())                                           // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))   // remove {outputStyle: 'compressed'} from saas() if do not want to minify css
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))                                      // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/css/editors'));

  src(['scss/editors/*.scss'])
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())                                           // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))   // remove {outputStyle: 'compressed'} from saas() if do not want to minify css
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))                                      // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(rtlcss())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.rtl' }))
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/css/editors'));

  src(['scss/libs/*.scss'])
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())                                           // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))   // remove {outputStyle: 'compressed'} from saas() if do not want to minify css
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))                                      // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/css/libs'));

  // SKINS
  src(['scss/skins/*.scss'])
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())               // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))  // uses {outputStyle: 'compressed'} in saas() for minify css
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))          // If you want generate source map.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/css/skins'));

  cb();
}

function js_scripts(cb) {
  src(['assets/src/js/*.js','!assets/src/js/bundle.js'])
  // .pipe(uglify())                        // If you minify the code.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/js'));

  src(['assets/src/js/charts/*.js'])
  .pipe(uglify())                        // If you minify the code.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/js/charts'));

  src(['assets/src/js/apps/*.js'])
  // .pipe(uglify())                        // If you minify the code.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/js/apps'));

  cb();
}

/* The task giving me the error */
function js_bundle(cb) {
  src('assets/src/js/bundle.js')
  .pipe(fileinclude({
    prefix: '@@',
    basepath: '@file',
    context: { build: 'dist', nodeRoot: node_path }
  }))
  .pipe(strip())
  .pipe(minify({ minify: true, minifyJS: { sourceMap: false } }))     // Disable, if you dont want to minify bundle file.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/js'));

  src(['assets/src/js/libs/**', '!assets/src/js/libs/editors/skins/**'])
  .pipe(fileinclude({
    prefix: '@@',
    basepath: '@file',
    context: { build: 'dist', nodeRoot: node_path }
  }))
  .pipe(strip())
  .pipe(minify({ minify: true, minifyJS: { sourceMap: false } }))     // Disable, if you dont want to minify bundle file.
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/js/libs'));

  src('assets/src/js/libs/editors/skins/**').pipe(dest('assets/dist/js/libs/editors/skins'));

  cb();
}

function assets(cb){
  src(['assets/src/**', '!assets/src/js/**', '!assets/src/css/**'])
  .pipe(dest('assets/dist/'));

  cb();
}

exports.build = series(html, scss, js_scripts, /* The task giving me the error */ js_bundle, assets);

exports.develop = function() {
    watch(['scss/*.scss','scss/**'], scss)
    watch(['html/src/*.html','html/src/**/*.html'], html)
    watch(['assets/src/**'], assets)
    watch(['assets/src/js/*.js','assets/src/js/charts/*.js', 'assets/src/js/apps/*.js', '!assets/src/js/bundle.js'], js_scripts)
    watch(['assets/src/js/libs/**','assets/src/js/bundle.js'], js_bundle)
};
```

*Here is the code snippet causing the error:*

```js
.pipe(fileinclude({
    prefix: '@@',
    basepath: '@file',
    context: { build: 'dist', nodeRoot: node_path }
}))
```

##### I tried the following:

- Updated the `gulp_file_include` plugin to the latest version which I suspect is causing the error.
- Console logged the functions before and after to check if the callback function is repeating but  to no avail.
- Removed the `strip` and `minify` functions but still got the error which confirms my doubt that the `gulp_file_include` plugin is causing the error.
- Checked this SO question [How to fix callback function called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166224/how-to-fix-write-callback-called-multiple-times) but I did not have the `gulp-imagemin` plugin which the author of the question had said was causing the problem

---

Any help is appreciated thanks, Ciao

Comment: Wow! Is gulp so obsolete? Anyone?.....

Comment: Gulp isn't quite obsolete, but it's definitely not top of the line anymore. Any chance you're running both `develop` and `build` in the same command? And what's your Node version? Because there was a change in Node 16 ([related issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39535)).

Comment: @ZacAnger Don't think so, Node version is 18.15.0. My guess is that this is most probably a bug or I am including a file which is running its own callback function multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its not an issue with the plugin itself. The error must be caused because you have some file (A) that is calling another file (B) that is calling again the first file (A) or something similar, making that they get looped. I suggest you to check the files thoroughly to ensure you are not falling into a loop.

If for some reason you have toooo much files, you can also test using [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to some point of the history to check, once you find a commit that works fine, you can compare that commit with the head using [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) to view which files has changes.

Extra: you shouldnt need to add prefix and basepath properties to fileinclude since those are their default value.

Hope this helps